# Running citrusframework Test Cases in Parallel

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider, citrus-framework

I am evaluating citrusframework to execute large number of test cases and many of them will be running with different sets of test data using data-provider feature. If test cases are executed sequentially (without parallel), total execution time would be huge and un-acceptable.

To reduce total testing time, I am evaluating option of running test cases in parallel using maven  parameter as well as threadPoolSize annotation for the method.

However, initial evaluation indicates that in case of parallel execution, TestContext passed to a method is shared in multiple concurrently running threads executing same test method. Also in case of test case execution with data-provider, same test context is passed for all running threads of a given test method. This causes conflicts of variables / messages stored in Message Store and fails to co-relate with request.

Does citrusframework supports test case executions in parallel without conflicting test variables / message store? Does it support concept similar to thread-local variables for each execution of a test case?

Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: Citrus is not prepared to run in multi threaded environment

Comment: This is not true. Citrus is able to be run by multiple threads. The only thing that might cause problems is the fact that there is a combination of parallel test execution and data providers.

Answer (score -1):

Citrus is not prepared to run in multi threaded environments